# Push only duplicates from array to new array (so they can be added together)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, push

I've seen many answers on how to remove duplicates but I need the opposite.
I have an array with duplicates. I need to form a new array with only the duplicates. However the duplicates are unknown and need to be discovered first so the whole process is automated.

```
    array = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 1
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 2
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 2
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 1
    }, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 4
    }]
```

Then this gets even more complicated because each duplicate needs to be pushed into its own array, and also a preferable method is if there is more than 2 of the item in the array only then this will be done.

(The end goal here is to calculate the totals on the duplicates, so perhaps there is a better solution for this?)

The end result should be something like:

```
array1 = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 1
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 2
    }]

array2 = [{
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 2
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }]
```

But the actual end result is simply to total the duplicates, as so (but I can already get this if the previous arrays can be generated):

```
array = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 6
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 15
    }]
```

Trying to get this result in either Javascript or PHP.

The closest I am so far is getting the unique items into a new array with PHP:

```
function get_duplicates ($array) {
    return array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) );
}
```

But this is only giving what the duplicates are.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: how do you know, that `array1` is related to `'cat'`?

Comment: I suppose my solution here would be to get the 'name' out of each array and this could be put into a variable such as array1Name. Make a function to extract the name based on the array length.

Comment: Following with the previous comment, an Array might not be the optimal data structure unless the solution's requirements state that the Array is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get an array of arrays for the grouped objects.

```js
var data = [{ name: "cat", amount: 1 }, { name: "cat", amount: 3 }, { name: "cat", amount: 2 }, { name: "dog", amount: 5 }, { name: "dog", amount: 3 }, { name: "dog", amount: 2 }, { name: "dog", amount: 5 }, { name: "duck", amount: 1 }, { name: "duck", amount: 4 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.name, (m.get(o.name) || []).concat(o)), new Map).values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh nice! This is helpful as I can then make a count on the array to determine the amount of duplicates, then do the math on each array for totalling the amounts for each item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var array = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 1
}, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 3
}, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 2
}, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
}, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 3
}, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 2
}, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
}, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 1
}, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 4
}];

var data = {};
for (var elem of array) {
    data[elem.name] = data[elem.name] || []
    if (data[elem.name]) {
        data[elem.name].push(elem);
    } else {
        data[elem.name] = [elem];
    }
}

var result = [];

for (var key in data) {
    var amounts = 0;
    for (var elem of data[key]) {
        amounts += elem.amount;
    }
    result.push({
        name: key,
        amount: amounts
    });
}


console.log(result);
// [{
//     "name": "cat",
//     "amount": 6
// }, {
//     "name": "dog",
//     "amount": 15
// }, {
//     "name": "duck",
//     "amount": 5
// }]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have just added details that the duplicates are unknown and need to be found within the code so it's an automated process.

Comment: Your mean is if I have element 'fish' but just one, I won't add it ?

Comment: Mean that `elem=>elem.name === "cat"` cannot be used because the name 'cat' is unknown.

Comment: You check result is your expected or not ?

Answer (score 0):

What about getting to end result directly? push to new array if not exist and accumulate amount if already exist

```js
array = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 1
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "cat",
    "amount": 2
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 3
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 2
    }, {
    "name": "dog",
    "amount": 5
    }, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 1
    }, {
    "name": "duck",
    "amount": 4
}];
let res = array.reduce((res, elem) => {
  let i = res.filter((e, i) => {
    if (e.name === elem.name) {
      e.amount += elem.amount
      return true
    }
    return false
  })
  if (i.length === 0) res.push(elem)
  return res
}, [])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? 
Could be refactored definitely, but you'll get the idea :)

```
const dupa = array.reduce((acc, { name, amount }) => {
  if (acc[name]) {
    return { ...acc, [name]: { amount: acc[name].amount + amount, count: acc[name].count += 1 }};
  }
  return { ...acc, [name]: { amount, count: 1}};
}, {});

const jaje = Object.keys(dupa)
  .filter(key => dupa[key].count > 2)
  .map(key => {
    return { name: key, amount: dupa[key].amount }    
})

console.log(jaje)
```

Working pen here.
https://codepen.io/_papiscript/pen/VGymjL?editors=0010